# Infinite loop while changing disabled attribute with a prop. (VueJs)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to change the disabled attribute of a button with a prop but when I change prop's value while instance is created it throws in an infinite loop.

This is parent component.

[image]

This is Button component.

[image]

This is the error when I change value of disabled prop from parent component.

[image]

Here's the full code of button component -

```
<template>
  <button 
    :class="[checkType(buttonType), checkIcon(icon)]"
    :disabled="disabled"
    @click="$emit('clicked'); buttonClicked();"
  >
    <p v-if="!icon && buttonType != 'iconOnly' && !buttonClickedBool">{{ buttonText }}</p>
    <div v-if="buttonClickedBool && loading" class="loader"> </div>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    buttonType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: "primary"
    },
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      buttonClickedBool: false,
      buttonText: "",
    }
  },

  methods: {
    checkType(buttonType) {
      this.buttonText = this.text;
      let buttonClass = "";
      if (buttonType === "primary") {
        buttonClass = "primary";
        this.buttonText = this.text.toUpperCase();
      } else if (buttonType === "secondary") {
        buttonClass = "secondary";
      } else if (buttonType === "textOnly") {
        buttonClass = "textOnly";
      } else if (buttonType === "iconOnly") {
        buttonClass = "iconOnly";
      }
      return buttonClass;
    },

    buttonClicked() {
      if(this.loading) {
      this.buttonClickedBool = true;
      }
      console.log("check")
    },

    checkIcon(icon) {
      let iconClass = "";
      switch (icon) {
        case 'like':
          iconClass = "like";
          return iconClass;
        case 'dislike':
          iconClass = "dislike";
          return iconClass;
        default:
          iconClass = '';
      }
    },
  },
  
};
</script>
```

Comment: do you use some computed properties somewhere

Comment: No. I've added the full code.

Comment: Could be that you've named the prop the same as an attribute, try renaming it `buttonDisabled`

Comment: I tried to change name of the prop but it still gives me same error.